# AWS Lambda for transformation of messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

My architecture is something like as:

SNS -> AWS Lambda -> Dynamo Db

SNS is publishing messages to which AWS Lambda function is the subscriber and then AWS Lambda pushes the data into Dynamo Db.

Is AWS Lambda good for doing transformations? Eg. I wanted to transform the message received by AWS Lambda to some other form and then pass it to downstream systems. By 'good', I mean is it normally done in AWS Lambda or for transformation, or I should use SQS Consumer probably for that?

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing Lambda is normally used for.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But transformation rules can be quite complex. Like for different kinds of messages, there would be different rules to transform it. Then, that file would become very large. Is there any way in AWS lambda function to split that file into multiple files and also I may want to transform into different kind of entities. Can I declare those entities as well in different files and all?

Comment: Your comment sounds like a different question than the one you originally posted, possibly multiple different questions, and all very broad. A single Lambda invocation has up to 1536MB of RAM, 512MB disk space, and can run for up to 5 minutes. If your process can execute using those constraints then AWS Lambda will probably work for you. If not then you may need a single SNS message to trigger multiple Lambda instances to split the job into different tasks, or you may need to use something other than Lambda.

Comment: @MarkB I have one more query if you could answer, please. Thanks a lot for answering all you have been till now. My question is basically as my transformer will get up to 1000 of lines of code, so is it a good practice to write such big code in aws lambda, or was it meant for small code only? Like, I am very confused now whether I should use SQS and then write SQS poller at consumer side or AWS Lambda. Please provide your suggestions.

Comment: People run much larger Lambda functions than that. As long as it fits within all the Lambda restrictions it should be fine.

Comment: This question is similar to [What are the drawbacks of SQS poller which AWS Lambda removes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469186/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-sqs-poller-which-aws-lambda-removes/44469509#44469509)

Comment: If you are worried about readability, you could set up Lambdas for each transformation and have the Lambda which is subscribing to SNS call the relevant transforming Lambda(s) depending on what type of message it is. But then you would have to manage the dependencies you are creating.